# Configure Azure search for Sitecore xConnect

Tags: xconnect, azure-search

Is there any document for configuring Azure search for xConnect.
I could see a link here : https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/search/configure-xconnect-search-providers/configure-azure-search-for-xconnect.html
But no steps to configure the same is provided

Also i need to know how the indexes will be built automatically.

We have documentation for rebuilding the indexes manually but how the normal indexes will be built, whether it should be done manually or whether automatic index build is available

https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/rebuild-index/rebuild-azure-index.html

Comment: I think the following link is helpful:
http://www.tibaf.com/azure-search-in-sitecore/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Enabling Azure Search**

To use xConnect and IndexWorker with Azure Search you need to do a couple of things:

- Create [Azure Search service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/search/) in your Azure subscription. Copy the service key which will be needed for connection strings.
- Disable SOLR configuration files by renaming them, e.g. to `*.disabled` and enable AzureSearch configuration files by removing `*.disabled` in the following locations:

  *xConnectRoot/App_Data/Config/Sitecore/CollectionSearch*

  *xConnectRoot/App_Data/Config/Sitecore/SearchIndexer*

  *xConnectRoot/App_Data/jobs/continuous/IndexWorker/App_Data/Config/Sitecore/CollectionSearch*

  *xConnectRoot/App_Data/jobs/continuous/IndexWorker/App_Data/Config/Sitecore/SearchIndexer*
- Update `collection.search` value in `xConnectRoot/App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config` file.

  *< add name="collection.search" connectionString="serviceUrl=https://[service name].search.windows.net;indexName=xdb;apiKey=[key]" />*
- Add `collection.search` connection string to `xConnectRoot/App_Data/jobs/continuous/IndexWorker/App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config` file.

  *< add name="collection.search" connectionString="serviceUrl=https://[service name].search.windows.net;indexName=xdb;apiKey=[key]" />*

**Rebuild**

Rebuild is not run automatically, but should be started manually by running console app: `\XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr`. Please take a look at the [official documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/rebuild-index/rebuild-azure-index.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I understood the point of rebuiding indexes, but need to know that how the indexes are normally synced initially, also how frequently it gets synced.

Comment: If by "synced" you mean "rebuilt", then I have to tell you that indexes are not automatically rebuilt at any point. Rebuild process has to be always kicked off manually.

Comment: But still, like sitecore indexes are updated automatically when we use default lucene and also solr. So here also the indexes must be updated manually right?

Comment: @Sreekrishnan it goes like this: as long as the indexer service is running contacts/interactions saved to XConnect are automatically indexed. So there are various reasons one would want to rebuild first, like when one switches to a different provider and one already had data.

Comment: there are some gotchas, like anonymous contacts not being indexed by default.